# Trying to unzip folder result in an error

Tags: c#

In below C# code, I am trying to unzip a folder and copy each file to different folder and I don't want to do unzip in some temp folder and then copy, all I want to do in memory. How to achieve this?

```
using (var za = ZipFile.OpenRead(sourceFile.FullName))
            {
                foreach (var entry in za.Entries)
                {
                    File.Copy(entry.FullName, "C:\\temp\\" + entry.FullName);
                }
            }
```

I'm getting an error:

> could not find the file while unzip a folder and copy file

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: You really ask?(it's not me) For once - what is the error ?

Comment: @sagi, the question subject itself has error

Comment: That's not clear at all

Comment: the  u can ask, why down vote?

Comment: Again, not my downvote.

Comment: _We shouldn't have to ask_ for the error message.  You're the person seeking help.  You should provide us with all the relevant information needed to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var entry in za.Entries)
{
    entry.ExtractToFile(destinationPath); 
}
```

See [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry?view=netframework-4.7.2)